# How to color the vertices of a graph so no adjacent vertices have the same color?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, color, vertex

How can I color the vertices of a graph so that no pair of adjacent vertices share the same color? The function `FindVertexColoring` can be used for this.

Answer (score 1):

This task is related to the four-color theorem and the vertex chromatic number of a graph. The four-color theorem states "All planar graphs can have their vertexes colored with four or fewer colors."

A `ResourceFunction` I published recently, named [ColorGraphVertices](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ColorGraphVertices/), accomplishes this.

The `ResourceFunction` accepts the options for `Graph`. By default the color list is `ColorData[106, "ColorList"]` but you can specify a second argument to adapt this to your liking. Interestingly, deciding whether a graph can be colored with 3 or more colors is an NP-complete problem.

There is a good example of the steps involved in the documentation for [FindVertexColoring](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindVertexColoring.html).
[image]
To color the edges of a graph, you can use [ColorGraphEdges](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ColorGraphEdge).

Comment: I think it is a bit unfair if somebody downvotes a question without leaving a comment explaining.

Comment: For those of us less familiar with graph theory, what is the difference between the function you advertised and `FindVertexColoring`? Please also add the code that generated the figure.

Comment: `ResourceFunction["ColorGraphVertices"][
 RandomGraph[BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[192, 3]], ImageSize -> Full]`. The exact image depends on $RandomGeneratorState (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$RandomGeneratorState.html), which you can set to a specific value with SeedRandom. Some functions that return random outputs like FindInstance accept the option RandomSeeding.

Comment: I think someone downvoted it because the documentation of FindVertexColoring has an example of how to do this.